# Which Haftora is it?

Tags: haftarah, riddle

Which Haftora do we recite on some years not even once, on some years once, on some years twice, and then on some years three times?

Answer (score 3):

The Haftarah for Shabbos Erev Rosh Chodesh.

Answer (score 3):

[מחר חודש](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90/%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9#.D7.A9.D7.91.D7.AA_.D7.A2.D7.A8.D7.91_.D7.A8.D7.90.D7.A9_.D7.97.D7.95.D7.93.D7.A9) ("*Machar Chodesh*")?

Comment: Specifically, in a non-leap year that starts on a Monday in which Marcheshvan and Kisleiv each have only 29 days.

Answer (score 2):

The Haftorah for Shabbos Rosh Chodesh also. It is not read at all in years that the Siman is זחא in most Shuls.

Comment: Nope - there is no year when we don't read that at least once.

Comment: How about 5710, 5711, 5776? And there are more!

Comment: In all of those it's actually a matter of minhag, as to whether the haftarah of Shabbos Rosh Chodesh is overridden by the one from תלתא דפורענותא or שבעה דנחמתא. With 5710 (זחא), it is true that the more widespread custom is to read 'שמעו דבר ה; but with 5711 and 5776 (גכז and בשז, respectively), it's a much more general custom to read the Shabbos Rosh Chodesh haftarah rather than עני' סערה, given that it's a haftarah of consolation too.